# Https post request with json response android error

Tags: android, rest, http-post

I am connecting to Restful Web Service and obtaining a JSON response.

I am able to send the request and handle the response in a JSON object,but the problem is that I receive an error:

```
Invalid api_key(is a parameter that I send,but I am sure is right).
```

Can you please help me to understand if there is a problem in my code or from WEB?

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpClient.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(new Scheme("SSLSocketFactory", SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));
HttpPost request = new HttpPost();
request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json, charset=utf-8");
request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
URI targetUri = new URI(TARGET_URL);
request.setURI(targetUri);
List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("api_key", "api_key"));
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user[email]", email));
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user[password]",pwd));

Log.i("","EMAIL REQUEST: "+email.toString());
Log.i("","PWD REQUEST: "+pwd.toString());
HttpEntity postEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters,"UTF-8");
request.setEntity(postEntity);
Log.i("","Request header "+request.getRequestLine());
Log.i("","Request : " +EntityUtils.toString(request.getEntity()));

httpClient.execute(request, myResponseHandler);
```

Comment: the scheme constructor takes the value of the scheme in argument. in your case, "https", not "SSLSocketFactory".

Comment: then you are declaring content-type application/json, but you are really sendind application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: then you don't seem to do anything with the result of execute ?

Comment: lead for finding where the error is from : log your request, make a test with curl using the reference implementation (there usualy is one using curl), compare both.

Comment: Hi njzk2,thank you to answer me.The SSLSocketFactory is used just because I don't receive back a certificate,so I implemented it just to manage that error.The request must be POST and the response will be json,so if that code is wrong how can I manage it?The result is managed in another part of code and is parsed from json in a String

Comment: Printing my https POST request:                                         Request : api_key=******&user%5Bemail%5D=mario.rossi%40mail.com&user%5Bpassword%5D=********
It should be api_key=*****&user[email]=mario.rossi%40mail.com&user[password]=*******
As you can see user[email] is changed in user%5B maybe this is the problem

Comment: the name of the scheme really should be "https". `[` => `%5B` is the direct and expected result of UrlEncodedFormEntity. Try your request with curl to see if it is the issue.

Comment: I fixed the problem,changing request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json, charset=utf-8");whit      request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded, charset=utf-8");
Now I am able to receive an answer,but is still what I am not expecting.Is there a way to pass data un-encoded?

Comment: i don't see the difference here ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the service you are addressing expectes an ACTUAL value in the API KEY:
`postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("api_key", "apy_key"));`

Replace the second operand to the APIkey you were given.

Comment: I also printed response STATUS LINE and is 401,it mean,maybe, that something is incorrect in the parameters I am sending.